# Does union support flexible array members?

Tags: c, c99, unions, flexible-array-member

I have declared a flexible array member in union, like this:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

union ut
{
    int i;
    int a[]; // flexible array member
};

int main(void)
{
    union ut s;
    return 0;
}
```

and compiler gives an error :

```
source_file.c:8:9: error: flexible array member in union
     int a[];
```

But, Declared array **zero** size like this :

```
union ut
{
    int i;
    int a[0]; // Zero length array
};
```

And it's working fine.

**Why does zero length array work fine union?**

Comment: Show your compile command.

Comment: Unions are more or less an amalgamation of types at *compile-time*. A flexible array member is really a run-time thing.

Comment: remove gnu support, and the second one will also throw error.

Comment: "Working fine"...wait..what? You mean compile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, unions do not support flexible array members, only structs. C11 6.7.2.1 §18

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
>   named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
>   *flexible array member*.

In addition, zero-length arrays is not valid C, that's a gcc non-standard extension. The reason why you get this to work is because your compiler, gcc, is configured to compile code for the "non-standard GNU language". If you would rather have it compile code for the C programming language, you need to add compiler options `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 8):

`int a[]` is the C standard notation (since [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)).

`int a[0]` is GNU C syntax, which predates C99. Other compilers might also support it, I don't know.

Your compiler seems to default to C90 standard with GNU extensions, which is why latter compiles, but first one does.

Furthermore, as stated in [Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46233509/1717300), standard C does not support flexible array members in `union` at all.

---

Try adding `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` to your compiler options ([*gcc* docs here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)).

Also `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` is probably a good idea too, it'll enforce more strict standard compliance.

And, obligatory aside, `-Wall  -Wextra` won't hurt either...

Comment: also `-pedantic`, maybe?

Comment: A compiler accepting `int a[0]` is not compliant, since zero-length arrays are explicitly forbidden in C.

Comment: GCC is not compliant without `-pedantic`.

Comment: @Lundin: A Conforming C Implementation may accept and usefully process such a construct provided it issues at least one diagnostic, and a Conforming C Program (but not Strictly Conforming C Program) may make use of such a construct provided that there exists somewhere in the universe a Conforming C Implementation that accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the standard would say about this, but G++' unions seems to accept flexible arrays just fine. If you wrap them in an anonymous struct first, like so:

```
union {
   unsigned long int  ul;
   char  fixed[4][2];
   struct {
      char  flexible[][2];
   };
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work these days if you compile with standard options like `-std=c11`, giving `error: flexible array member in a struct with no named members`.